# Why Mysql order by doesn't work for this query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT *    
FROM ( 
  SELECT p.id, product, unique_name, price, old_price, category_id, added_date    
  FROM products p, products_to_categories ptc, products_to_adverts pta 
  WHERE p.id=ptc.product_id AND (expire_date > now() OR expire_date=0) 
    AND p.id=pta.product_id AND p.active=1 AND p.instock=1 AND p.top_product="1" 
    and p.id not in (58,59,70,88,92,106,107,108,109) 
    and pta.advert_id not in (1,4,5,6,7,9,13,15,17) 
    ORDER BY added_date DESC
) as t GROUP BY id LIMIT 0,32
```

added_date field is datetime

Thanks !

Comment: Apart from your query nesting not making any sense, your `GROUP BY id` is probably interfering with the `ORDER BY` of the subquery.

Comment: a alias of added_date

Comment: You'll need to add the schema and preferably some sample data/desired result to get complete help on this query, but `GROUP BY` in the outer query will remove all ordering created by `ORDER BY` in your inner query, giving no ordering of the output.

Comment: yes, you are all right.. problem solved by moven order by at proper place, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use order by in subquery. Try using temporary table instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use order by like this inside the query .As I think this is wrong.If you can do this using sql `CASE`

Follow this article.

[http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/][1]